# Get a list of users that are associated with taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

In WP, I would like to get the list of user IDs that are associated with taxnomy.
I know the SQL query but I am not sure how to build a line of php code to get the same result (something like $users  = get_user_by(parameters)) ?

```
SELECT u.ID
FROM wp_users u
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r
ON u.ID = r.object_id
WHERE u.user_status = 0
AND r.term_taxonomy_id = 1186
```

turning this into something like this

```
$users  = get_user_by(parameters) or 
get_objects_in_term(parameters)
```

I have checked a few posts online but very few post about user-taxonomy relation... so please help me....

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Next to reading posts, have you tried with the actual documentation? Post often only care about one or two parameters, the documentation covers all parameters (and if not, it should link the source code where parameters are often relatively easy to spot, too)

Comment: Which would explain why it's not working: [get_user_by()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) supports only a limited set of fields. Taxonomy is not part of it. However what prevents you to write your own function with the query and then run get_user_by() for the returned ID?

Comment: I am not sure about the full document, I am not a php person.. with some research, I have come across a few posts to use 'get_objects_in_term' but didnt manage to fully get it out...

I believe that it should be passing the result from the one query to another input parameter..

Comment: tip: google/search: codex + the function name interested in. normally brings you to the docs at the right place. / for the parameter passing: your SQL query returns the user-ID(s), with get_user_by() you can then get the user by the user-ID. Just in case that was not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to get all users using the `get_users()` function. then iterate the loop of users and based on that get user posts using `author` and `tax_query`. try below code.

```
$user_args = array( 'orderby' => 'ID' );

$users = get_users($user_args);

//Loop through each peche author
foreach($users as $user){

    $user_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product', // your custom post type
        'author'         => $user->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // your custom taxonomy slug
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => 22 // your term id.
            )
        )
    ));

    if( $user_posts->have_posts() ) { 

        echo $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name. ' associated with taxonomy 22'."</br>";

    } 
}
```

**UPDATE as per OP requested**

```
$user_args = array( 
    'include' => array(11, 33, 52, 57, 997) // add your user ids here by comma seprate.
);

$users = get_users( $user_args );

//Loop through each peche author
foreach($users as $user){

    $user_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product', // your custom post type
        'author'         => $user->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // your custom taxonomy slug
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => 22 // your term id.
            )
        )
    ));

    if( $user_posts->have_posts() ) { 

        echo $user->ID."</br>";

    } 
}
```

**UPDATE** as per OP requested in comments.

```
$all_ids = array();

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT u.ID FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON u.ID = r.object_id WHERE u.user_status = 0 AND r.term_taxonomy_id = 1186", ARRAY_A );

foreach ( $result as $key => $id ) {
    $all_ids[] = $id['ID'];
}

if( !empty( $all_ids ) ){
    echo implode( ',', $all_ids );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Its' much longer than I thought.. 

Just for my knowledge, i am not a php person (more to sql guy), why 'posts_per_page'=> -1 ?  what is this line for?

Comment: `posts_per_page` how many posts do you need as a return per page.

Comment: I just need to get the list of user_id (11, 33, 52, 57, 997...) and return the values like echo $user_id... something like that... 

Where should I amend? 

Thank you..

Comment: I am sorry for the trouble, maybe I was not clear... 

11,33,52... are just an example of the result that I need to get out from the php. 

I want to get a list of user id of the user(s) who are associated with taxonomy_id = 1182.

With that, your updated anwer is still getting that result?

Comment: Plus, I have 20K users... I see the loop from your code.. is it good practice to loop thru 20k users?.. or maybe this is only way to get the result due to some limitation?

Comment: With that, your updated answer is still getting that result? => Yes you please read the comments that I have added in the code you will know what to do.

Comment: Works great on my end!

Comment: Thank you but i am approaching a bit different way as below. Please help.

I got the result from the following wpdb function.. the result shows this way 
https://prnt.sc/1xszmpk

$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT u.ID FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON u.ID = r.object_id WHERE u.user_status = 0 AND r.term_taxonomy_id = 1186");

I would like to echo this result out into following way 
27,50,148,160,212,234.....

How do i achieve this? 
Thank you!